# Setting up IIS for Web Service

Tags: javascript, vb.net, iis-7

I cannot get any of the tutorials or setup instructions to allow a Web Service to be consumed by a javascript function. On my PC, Chrome just throws a

> 500 (Internal Server Error)

, and running the web page from the server, IE throws

> required Cross Origin Resource Sharing (CORS).

and

> required CORS preflight.

I've added the required cross domain settings to the webconfig, yet it still doesn't work.

```
<configuration>
    <system.web>
      <customErrors mode="Off"/>
      <compilation strict="false" explicit="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
      <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5"  />
      <webServices>
        <!-- added because asmx -->
        <protocols>
          <add name="HttpGet"/>
          <add name="HttpPost"/>
        </protocols>
      </webServices>
    </system.web>
  <system.webServer>
    <httpProtocol>
      <customHeaders>
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="Content-Type" />
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS" />
      </customHeaders>
    </httpProtocol>
  </system.webServer>

</configuration>
```

Javascript:

```
function GetMember() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "https://www.mywebsite.org/Callsickapp/Webservice1.asmx/HelloWorld",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: OnGetMemberSuccess,
        error: OnGetMemberError
    });
}
document.getElementById("btnCallService").onclick = GetMember;
function OnGetMemberSuccess(data, status) {
    //jQuery code will go here...

    document.getElementById("answers").innerHTML= data.d;
}
function OnGetMemberError(request, status, error) {
    //jQuery code will go here...
    document.getElementById("answers").innerHTML= request.statusText
}
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just needed to actually read the comment at the top of the web service .vb file generated by Visual Studio.

```
'To allow this Web Service to be called from script, using ASP.NET AJAX, uncomment the following line.

' <System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService()> _
```

Simple "HelloWorld" web service, and other web services from tutorials work fine now.